# Is there a way to cover the whole window area within a web site, using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, otherwise I just starting make my wrapper in CSS so it covers 770px or 990 px etc..

It should be like scaling after window size/resolution.
Are their any way to make it adjustable for every single computer using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: So you are wanting to determine the size of the browser window and adjust html elements accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are this way really smooth? I've always learned to avoid absolute positioning.

Comment: That's ridiculous, css absolute positioning will ALWAYS be faster than anything javascript can achieve. And it's sooooo useful.

Comment: Agreed, there's absolutely no reason to avoid absolute positioning